# Quick international football riddle (sort of)

Tags: riddle

When football/soccer is broadcast live on TV, the score is displayed throughout the match in the corner of the screen, using the first three letters of each team name as an abbreviation. (e.g. GER for Germany)

However occasionally when Sweden are playing, all six letters of their name are displayed.

Why?

Comment: you made it too easy by saying the country name. You should have asked at which game a country name is fully displayed. (or something like that).

Comment: But then there would be more than one possible solution: POL-AND, CYP-RUS, ...

Comment: @Schorsch. that was the fun of it :)

Comment: I'm still waiting for the person who sues his cable company for rasicm when broadcasting the match between Nigeria and Germany...

Comment: The really fun match-ups are ones like Australia vs Austria or Belgium vs Belarus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens for the game:

> Sweden vs Denmark.

The displayed score at the start of the game is :

> SWE 0 - 0 DEN

Funny Off topic fact

> The missing letters from the country names form the name of the other country (Denmark).
>  SWE**DEN** - DEN**MARK**

Comment: damnit was answering the same. :) +1

Comment: Well the funny OT fact is not a coincidence, it's a corollary of the original observation.
For any other countries (or any words for that matter), where first is somethingXYZ and the other is XYZwhatever, swapping XYZ for XYZ will leave not only the first, but both words without a change.

Comment: This is one of my favourite fun facts.

Comment: @Meiffert. I know, but I just thought it would be fun to point that out.